# Which packages to reference in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor project to get full ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create a modular Web application using ASP.NET Core.

So my structure is to have a full ASP.NET Core application project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

and multiple projects of type

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
```

The reason for using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` is that it doesn't require a `Program.cs` with a static `Main` method.

However, when I try to reference e.g. `IViewLocationExpander` it is not available due to the lack of some assembly references.

My problem now is which version of the overwhelming list of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages to pick in which version (for .NET 6 I expect to be something like `6.0.12`).

`IViewLocationExpander` is part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor in assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor `(`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll`).

But `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor` is only available until version `2.2.0` so it seems to be outdated.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you considered using `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` - it avoids a lot of the headaches with working out which packages to reference and gets you all the Razor ones (and all the other useful ASP.NET Core bits) out of the box.

Comment: if you look at the Ms docs for IViewLocationExpander, it says it's now in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref package. Have you tried letting your IDE "auto-find" the necessary packages?

Comment: Should be part of the Razor SDK when you set your project sdk to "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" they are automatically referenced. At least in my project. Do you have the sdk available? see C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Razor. You could try to install the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor nuget.

Comment: @DeanWard Thanks, this did the trick. Searching for `FrameworkReference` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` brought up this MS docs article as a first result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Tim I tried this already but it didn't work. Nuget package readme also says the package isn't intended for direct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` in your project file should do the trick - it avoids a lot of the headaches with working out which packages to reference and gets you all the Razor ones (and all the other useful ASP.NET Core bits) out of the box.

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856028/which-packages-to-reference-in-microsoft-net-sdk-razor-project-to-get-full-asp-n/74862841#comment132116193_74856028) by @Alexander in the comments the docs for this are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0